# Count for Group of Shape with different color

Tags: vba, excel

I have 4 shapes in one group in Excel Workbook, I want is when I color 2 shapes in yellow, Cells(6, 21) will appear 1 and cells(6, 22) will appear 2, and the other 2 shapes I color in blue, cells(9, 21) still remain 0 and Cells(9, 22) are 2.

Below is my vba code I apply in my workbook but did not work as I want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim shprange As ShapeRange
Dim CountyellowShape As Long
Dim CountorangeShape As Long
Dim CountpinkShape As Long
Dim CountblueShape As Long

For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes

    If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
        Set shprange = shp.Ungroup
        Set oMyGroup = shprange.Group

        If shprange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then CountChildShapeYELLOW = CountChildShapeYELLOW + 0.5
        If shprange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then CountChildShapeORANGE = CountChildShapeORANGE + 0.5
        If shprange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 102, 153) Then CountChildShapePINK = CountChildShapePINK + 0.5
        If shprange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240) Then CountChildShapeBLUE = CountChildShapeBLUE + 0.5

    End If
Next shp

For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
    If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then CountShapeYELLOW = CountShapeYELLOW + 0.5
    If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then CountShapeORANGE = CountShapeORANGE + 0.5
    If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 102, 153) Then CountShapePINK = CountShapePINK + 0.5
    If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240) Then CountShapeBLUE = CountShapeBLUE + 0.5
Next shp

Sheet1.Cells(6, 21) = CountShapeYELLOW + CountChildShapeYELLOW
Sheet1.Cells(7, 21) = CountShapeORANGE + CountChildShapeORANGE
Sheet1.Cells(8, 21) = CountShapePINK + CountChildShapePINK
Sheet1.Cells(9, 21) = CountShapeBLUE + CountChildShapeBLUE


    For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
        Set shprange = shp.Ungroup
        For Each grpShp In shprange

          If grpShp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then CountChildShapeYELLOW = CountChildShapeYELLOW + 0.5
          If grpShp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then CountChildShapeORANGE = CountChildShapeORANGE + 0.5
          If grpShp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 102, 153) Then CountChildShapePINK = CountChildShapePINK + 0.5
          If grpShp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240) Then CountChildShapeBLUE = CountChildShapeBLUE + 0.5
        Next grpShp
        shprange.Group
    Else
      If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then CountShapeYELLOW = CountShapeYELLOW + 0.5
      If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then CountShapeORANGE = CountShapeORANGE + 0.5
      If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 102, 153) Then CountShapePINK = CountShapePINK + 0.5
      If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240) Then CountShapeBLUE = CountShapeBLUE + 0.5
    End If
Next shp

Sheet1.Cells(6, 22) = CountShapeYELLOW + CountChildShapeYELLOW
Sheet1.Cells(7, 22) = CountShapeORANGE + CountChildShapeORANGE
Sheet1.Cells(8, 22) = CountShapePINK + CountChildShapePINK
Sheet1.Cells(9, 22) = CountShapeBLUE + CountChildShapeBLUE

End Sub
```

Thanking in advance.
Wiz Lee

Comment: very poor explanation. i have no idea what you want.  saying `did not work as I want` does not explain anything about what happens when you run the code, so it does not help to create a solution for your problem. ... so in effect, you posted some code and said `it does not work`  ....  all i can say `well, change your code so that it does what you want, whatever that is`

Comment: I really sorry about my English is very bad and make you helpless. When I run the code, If I put the different color in group shift, Cells(6, 21) will change to 0. I need the Cells(6, 21) remain as 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below looks at the fill colour for each shape in the worksheet and counts the number of shapes with the 4 colours you have specified. The result will be in the array ColorCount(1 To 4). Shapes with other colours will be ignored.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' 18 Nov 2017

    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim ColorCount(1 To 4) As Long
    Dim n As Long

    With Sheet1
        For Each Shp In .Shapes
            On Error Resume Next
            n = Application.Match(Shp.Fill.ForeColor, _
                Array(39423, vbYellow, 10053375, 15773696), 0)
                ' 1 = orange, 2 = yellow, 3 = pink, 4 = blue
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                ColorCount(n) = ColorCount(n) + 1
            End If
        Next Shp

        For n = 1 To 4
            Debug.Print n, Split("Orange yellow pink blue")(n - 1) & ": " & ColorCount(n)
        Next n
'        .Cells(6, 22) = CountShapeYELLOW + CountChildShapeYELLOW
'        .Cells(7, 22) = CountShapeORANGE + CountChildShapeORANGE
'        .Cells(8, 22) = CountShapePINK + CountChildShapePINK
'        .Cells(9, 22) = CountShapeBLUE + CountChildShapeBLUE
    End With
End Sub
```

The above code prints the count to the Immediate Window (Debug.Print) for testing purposes only. The algorithm by which the result should be translated into values to be written to the sheet isn't sufficiently explain in your question. Obviously, this transformation must take place after the count is done and before its result can be written to the sheet. Perhaps, with the count in  hand, you will be able to do that. Else, please explain the meaning of what you want written to the sheet..

Comment: I am sorry about my explanation was very bad. What I try to explain is my code is work to appear number(1) in Cells(6,21) but just only when I put the same color in the group shape. I want the Cells(6,21) stills remain as number(1) no matter what the color the group shape.

Comment: It seems that F21 and F22 are both related to yellow. There could be 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 yellow shapes. Since you have 2 cells to fill there are 8 possible combinations resulting from the count, not counting the possibility of leaving the cells blank. Your rule seems to say, "if there is one or more yellow shape, write 1 in F21, else leave it blank". Please confirm. What is the rule for F22? Are cells G21:I22 to be treated analog for the other colours?

Comment: F21 is count on group, if there have 3 group of shape color in yellow, F21 will write as 3, and F22 is count on shape, if 5 shapes per group, F22 will write as 5. Yes, G21 is orange, H21 is pink and I21 is blue color.

Comment: Around 22 group.

Comment: So, if 11 of the 22 groups have any number of yellow, F21 will be 11. As for F22, if all 22 groups have 5 shapes each F22:I22 should all be 5. But do all groups have the same number of shapes?

Comment: Let me explain it, I have 22 group on the sheet, every group have 5 shapes each. If in 22 group I have 10 groups are yellow color, F21 will be 10, F22 will be 50, 5 groups are orange color, G21 will be 5, G22 will be 25, 3 groups are pink color, H21 will be 3, H22 will be 15 and 4 groups are blue color, I21 will be 4, I22 will be 20.

Comment: Looks clear enough, for now. Please just confirm that all five shapes in each group will always have the same colour, F22 will always be =F21*5

Comment: No, the color will change in anytime.

Comment: That isn't my question. I asked if all 5 shapes will always have the same colour, like, before change all yellow and after change all blue.

Comment: Certain of shape will not same color, meaning there have 3 shape are yellow and 2 shape are blue in a group.

Comment: I have 110 shapes. I count 23 yellow. Do I need to record that number anywhere?

Comment: How can I upload the attachment file that I can show you my worksheet? It will be more easy to explain it.

Comment: I believe you can attach a picture of your worksheet to your original question, but your answer about the 23 count will help. Then perhaps two or three more yes/no questions.

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://app.box.com/s/77ggn7fobdv6reh1u5ag0om7wln0pso8)

Can you Open this link?
I have no qualify to upload a image due to reputation requirement.